# SYMFONY2 ¿Puedo tener un archivo de traducción especifico por ID de Usuario?

Tags: symfony2

Deseo Sobreescribir traducciones.

Quiero que en mis traducciones globales tener por ejemplo

> Agente: Agente 
>   País: Pais

Pero que cuando exista un archivo por `ID` de usuario pueda sobreescribir las traducciones de estos es decir que si el usuario con `ID` 1 ingresa, el sistema cargue un archivo en /src/Resources/translations/1/messages.es.yml y su traducción sea:

> Agente: Operario

Y como no está Pais que lo tome de la global.

De Antemano Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo jugando un poco con las capacidades de Symfony, el componente Translator y Twig.

En primer lugar debes generar, como siempre, el fichero de traducciones, por ejemplo: messages.es.yml (o cualquier otro tipo de fichero de traducciones)

Para las cadenas de texto a cambiar, crea un fichero específico, por ejemplo, para el usuario *muriano*, creamos `muriano.es.yml`, y aquí tendremos las traducciones que difieren de nuestro original. A esto se le llama "dominio" de traducción. Puedes aprender más sobre esto aquí: http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates

Para traducir una cadena específica usando un dominio distinto a `messages`, que el dominio por defecto, lo hacemos así:

Desde `Twig`, usando bloque `trans`:

```
{% trans with {'%name%': 'Muriano'} from app.user.username %}Hello %name%{% endtrans %}
```

Le pasamos "from `domain`", que en este caso es el valor del username del usuario identificado en la plataforma. Obviamente tendrás que hacer las comprobaciones oportunas.

Desde `Twig`, usando filtro `trans`:

```
{{ message|trans({'%name%': 'Muriano'}, app.user.username) }}
```

En esta ocasión, el primer parámetro que pasamos es un objecto con los valores a sustituir, el segundo, es el `dominio de traducción`. En este caso también tendrás que hacer comprobaciones para saber si el usuario está identificado. Es sencillo.

Podrías también, hacer una única comprobación al inicio de la plantilla twig y establecer el dominio de la traducción para todas las traducciones que se hagan en la plantilla de la siguiente manera:

```
{% trans_default_domain "domain" %}
```

En este caso, lo haríamos así:

```
{% trans_default_domain app.user.username %}
```

Tras haber realizado las comprobaciones de rigor. ¿Cuál es el problema de este método? Que tendrás que duplicar todas las cadenas de message.es.yml en muriano.es.yml. Para contrarrestar este inconveniente, puedes crear un domino de respaldo, es algo que Symfony no soporta actualmente, pero que puedes implementar tú mismo y fácilmente tal como lo explican aquí: https://worksonmymachine.org/blog/fallback-translation-domain

Comment: Gracias, es casi perfecto lo que me enviaste, y lo entendí bien, pero despues me puse a mirar el dominio de falla de las traducciones y aunque entendi la clase, no supe en donde agregar al dependencyInjector la clase del fallbackTranslator.

Comment: Tienes que tener un archivo dentro de app/config llamado services (que puede ser yml o xml) Ese es el sitio. Para más información puedes leer http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos de traducciones de Symfony están pensados para albergar traducciones estáticas por idioma.

Si lo que deseas es almacenar traducciones dinámicas lo suyo es almacenarlas en base de datos. Bien mediante alguna implementación manual o bien utilizando un bundle de traducciones, como por ejemplo GedmoTranslatable.

https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/translatable.md

De esta forma podrás indicar para cada ID de usuario y para cada columna, que traducción quieres cargar.

Comment: Puede hacerse usando dominios de traducciones.